# Librería en programación orientada a objetos

Tags: java

Desarrolle una librería en Java que contenga las siguientes funciones para manipulación de cadenas.

1.- Determine si una cadena de caracteres es palindromo.

2.- Determine si una cadena de caracteres contiene un diptongo.

3.- Determine la longitud de una cadena de caracteres.

4.- Codifique una cadena de caracteres.

5.- Decodifique una cadena de caracteres.

Para la codificación y decodificación considere:

i=1

z=2

e=3

a=4

s=5

g=6

t=7

b=8

q=9

o=0

Ademas desarrolle una aplicación en java que implemente la biblioteca y pruebe las funciones con una cadena ingresada por el usuario.

Comment: tu pregunta, si es una pregunta, no es muy clara, podrías desarrollarla más?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español , da un [tour] y revisa [ask] para que puedas formular una pregunta que sea aceptada por la comunidad. Muestra lo que has intentado, ya que aquí no se resuelven los ejercicios académicos, no si al menos no se ha realizado un esfuerzo por solucionarlo.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, es demasiado importante revises los documentos que te comparte @YemisiSCG y modifiques tu pregunta por favor, saludos.

Comment: parece que estas queriendo que te desarrollen una tarea?

Comment: Parece un trabajo que te han pedido en la escuela.

Answer (score 2):

```
    /*
    *En Eclipse te dirigís a menú File, new, Java Project, lo nombras como 
    *LibreriaCadena.
    *Creas un paquete llamado Cadena haciendo click con el derecho en src,
    *new,Package y lo nombras como Cadena.
    *En el paquete Cadena, creas una clase llamada LibreriaCadena que es la
    *siguiente
    */

    package Cadena;

    public class LibreriaCadena {
    private String cadena;
    public LibreriaCadena(String cadena) {
    this.cadena=cadena;
    }
    ...
/*
* una vez hecha la clase,sigues los siguientes pasos en Eclipse:
*click con el derecho en el projecto de java,export,Jar File,en 
*Select export destination: pones la ruta donde queres guardar el archivo.jar
*señalale la ruta y ponele de nombre LibreriaCadena luego,  Finish.


*Agregar la librería al nuevo proyecto

*Crea un nuevo Java Proyect, luego en el nombre del nuevo proyecto
*hace click con el boton derecho del mouse, Build Path, Configure build path...
*Pestaña Libraries, add external Jars...
*Seleccionas la ubicación de tu libreria.
*y luego una main de prueba. 
*/

import Cadena.Cadena;
import Cadena.LibreriaCadena;

public class PruebaCadena {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    LibreriaCadena c1 = new LibreriaCadena("anana");

    System.out.println(c1.getCadena()+" es palindromo" + c1.isPalindromo());
    System.out.println(c1.getCadena() +" tiene diptongo "+c1.tieneDiptongo());
    c1.setCadena("hacia");

    System.out.println(c1.getCadena() +" tiene diptongo "+c1.tieneDiptongo());
    System.out.println(c1.getCadena() +" su longitud es "+c1.longitud());
    System.out.print(c1.getCadena() +" codificada es ");
    c1.codificar();
    System.out.println(c1.getCadena());
    System.out.print(c1.getCadena() +" decodificada es ");
    c1.deCodificar();
    System.out.println(c1.getCadena());

 }

}
```